# Python - get elements from list

Tags: python, list

From a python function, I get the following output:

```
['(0.412169, mississippi)']
```

The type indicates that it is a list.  I want to extract the values from the list and save it as separate elements.  I tried various functions to convert list to tuple, list to str, extracting the element by Index from the tuple or str, nothing worked out.  When I try to extract the element by index, I either get '(' for the first element index 0, or when I try to extract through a iterator function, I get all the values split up like the full data set as a string.

How do I get values separately.

Comment: As the question has been closed, here the solution: You have first to get rid of the paranthesis in the string expression:

    `string = ['(0.412169, mississippi)']`
    `elems = string[0].replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',')`
Output:
    `['0.412169', ' mississippi']`

Comment: How'd you get that string in the first place? Can that be changed to something more parseable at the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over your data, remove the parentheses using slicing and split the string by comma to create a list, which will be appended to your output payload:

```
data = ['(0.412169, mississippi)', '(0.412180, NY)']
extracted_values = []
for d in data:
    extracted_values += d[1:-1].split(",")
print(extracted_values) 
# output: ['0.412169', ' mississippi', '0.412180', ' NY']
```

Answer (score -1):

Your list content a string, not a list.
If you want to extract the content of a string, use the "eval" statement

```
my_tuple = eval("(0.412169, 'mississippi')")
```

Note that the "eval" function can be dangerous, because if your string content python code, it could be executed.

Comment: Right, use `ast.literal_eval` instead!

Comment: OP is having `['(0.412169, mississippi)']` to start with. Notice there are no quotes around string.